# Issue with buttons on Android

Tags: java, android

I got my layout nicely done with only a couple of problems left: I can't get to work the mailto and the facebook link buttons. This is what I've tried:

```
ImageView Button = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonsId);

Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yourURL.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

and

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourID);

textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.typeyourURL.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    } });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanna use mailto than put an EditText in your xml and a button for mail.
User will add his Email id in edittext and press button to send mail. when send button is clicked you can write like

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {

Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
    "mailto",yourEditTextObj.getText(), null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(
        "mailto","abc@gmail.com", null));
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Body");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

Comment: hi , thanks for the response, but how can i use this code ? do i have to do a xml just for this ?   im at mainactivity.xml i dont know how to work around android

Comment: put it into onClick()